# How to use custom font using CustomAdapter

Tags: android, adapter, custom-font, getview

I am using simple ListAdapter. I want to use custom font in it. I was suggested to use getView() but as a beginner i am unaware of using custom adapter. Can someone help it.

Comment: how much i know you want to use the ttf file for the custom font then set it on your textview or any where else you desire

Comment: I know that...I m looking for implementation solution

Comment: ok wait i am sending you an example of that

Comment: May be my answer help you

Answer (score -1):

first of all put any ttf file in your asset folder then put on your textview like this

Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                precious.ttf);//or any other ttf you want

```
                    String edittextString = title.getText().toString();

                    title.setText("");
                    title.setTypeface(face);
                    title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(hexColor));
                    if (edittextString != null) {
                        title.setText(edittextString);
                    }
```

Comment: Hasnain - Thanks but i know it. I am looking it to implement custom adapter. Please answer relevantly. Thanks once again

Comment: ok i am sorry i was unable to get you problem sorry and thanks.

Comment: No problem...Thanks once again